# Problems of loading R packages using Rstudio server

Tags: r, raster, gdal, rgdal

I am using conda R. I found that some packages (i.e., sf, raster, rgdal, terra) could not be successfully loaded using Rstudio server (but could be loaded using terminal R!)

I have checked I am using the same version of R in terminal and rstudio server.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thank you for any help!
Here is the error code

```
 unable to load shared object '/home/liao/miniconda3/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so':
  /home/liao/miniconda3/lib/R/library/rgdal/libs/../../../../libgdal.so.34: undefined symbol: sqlite3_total_changes64
```